# Syntax error for asp - sqlGet

Tags: asp.net, syntax-error

I am trying to create an asp file that references a database. I have entered the code to show the customer name as follows.

```
Dim sqlGetCategoryName,rsCategoryName
sqlGetCategoryName = "Select CategoryName from Categories where CategoryID = "&
rsProductList("CategoryID")&""
Set rsCategoryName = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsCategoryName.open sqlGetCategoryName, adoCon

Dim catName
catName = rsCategoryName("CategoryName")
rsCategoryName.Close
Set rsCategoryName = Nothing
```

When I try to load the page a syntax error comes up for the line -

```
sqlGetCategoryName = "Select CategoryName from Categories where CategoryID = "&
```

I cannot see where I have made a mistake. Any assistance that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what error exactly?

Comment: Sorry should have included that.

This is exactly what comes up - 


Script error detected at line 40. 
Source line: sqlGetCategoryName = "Select CategoryName from Categories where CategoryID = "& 
Description: Syntax error

Comment: try replacing `sqlGetCategoryName = "Select CategoryName from Categories where CategoryID = "&
rsProductList("CategoryID")&""` with `sqlGetCategoryName = "Select CategoryName from Categories where CategoryID = " & rsProductList("CategoryID")`... anyway, take a look at "Parametrized Queries", you could fix this in a more elegant way and using best practices for SQL commands